# Laravel "The 'name' argument does not exist" Error

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel php developent. I have alredy existing mysql database. I heard about `ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator` to generate Eloquent models from existing database.It uses `php artisan make:models`  command to generate models. But while doing I am getting error `The "name" argument does not exist.`.

https://packagist.org/packages/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator

link will all about I tried.

can anyone here help me about this?

Comment: What is the full command you're using? It may be hard to track this down since the package is abandonware.

Comment: `php artisan make:models`  this is command i am using

Comment: Looking at the issues of the package, someone suggested using https://github.com/reliese/laravel instead. Not sure if it will work any better for you.

Comment: Using github.com/reliese/laravel gives error `In Filesystem.php line 442:  mkdir(): Invalid path `

Comment: https://github.com/reliese/laravel/issues/24

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you care to provide some code?

Comment: I am trying to generate Eloquent models from existing database rather than writing them manually. I haven't changed any default configuration of laravel.

Comment: @aynber thank you, It works using  reliese/laravel

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely using `make:model` command. You can't possibly get this error message when using `make:models` command from the package.

The problem is you're using this command without specifying model name. So, specify model name:

```
php artisan make:model Article
```

But `php artisan make:model` will not create a model based on existing BD. It will just create a model stub for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: They're using a package, not the default Laravel artisan commands. The error is regards to the `ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator` package.

Comment: @aynber yes, but OP gets an error because he's using `php artisan make:model` and not packages' command.

Comment: No, they're using `make:models` with an s, which is the command for the package.

Comment: No. Error is while using `ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator`

Comment: @aynber if you'll look into Laravel source code and in the package's source code, you'll understand you can get this error only with `make:model` command and you can't possibly get it with `make:models` command. Please take a minute and look into source code and remove the downvote 
 if you'll agree with me after learning the package's code.

Comment: @aynber I'll help you with the link: https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator/blob/master/src/Commands/MakeModelsCommand.php

Comment: I have the link, thanks, and I've been looking at it. And yeah, I can't see where in the code that would come from.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote, but I'm also going to vote to close because this about someone else's package without any code or troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Package `ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator` is abandoned, you should **avoid using it**.

Use `reliese/laravel` instead.

Comment: Ok. I ll try that one. Thanks.